# Install Craft 3 with craft in web root

Tags: craft3

I've got a staging environment where in need to install Craft 3 in the web root rather than above the root as in normally recommended. Like so:

```
my-project.test/web
    config/
    storage/
    templates/
    vendor/
    .env
    .env.example
    composer.json
    craft.bat
    index.php
```

I'm struggling to set the correct CRAFT_BASE_PATH for this configuration. I've tried using the full path to the web root with no success in addition to some variations on using **DIR**. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've relaunched this staging site on a secondary domain so no longer have need to use the configuration described in the original question, but would still be curious to know a solution to this issue.

Comment: Can you post your file structure in the question, please?

Comment: I'm curious about this one as well. I have the non /web/* content sitting inside of /craft/ next to index.php, .htaccess, /cpresources/* and web.config. Can't seem to get it to work.